# Tcl/Tk bind mouse click in toplevel bar

Tags: tcl, bind, tk-toolkit, toplevel

I'm developing some applications in Tcl/Tk and I would like to add on my GUIs a function to minimize the windows leaving the toplevel in the current position of screen.
This picture better explains my idea.

[image]

When the mouse pointer is in the bar (sorry if the name is wrong but I don't know the technical name of that part of GUI) I press mouse button and the window becomes as below.

I add this row in my scripts for a test

```
bind . <Button-3> "wm geometry . 200x1"
```

But this work fine only in the frame area of toplevel. My problem is bind the event when the mouse is exactly in position of the figure.
Anyone know how can I do so?

Thanks in advance for help

Comment: (That's a 'shade' action).  You can look into the twapi package and see if Windows has an API that can be used.  `bind . <Configure>` does not capture a single-click action.

Comment: The window manager will not notify the application (root window) when a click event occurs on the title bar. There are ways around this. One way is to remove the title bar and then create a custom one yourself. Use wm overrideredirect. This is somewhat involved because now you will probably want to replicate all the nice features the window manager provides like resizing the window, closing it, minimizing, etc. You lose all those provided features. But you do achieve what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do what you want. Tk has very little control over what happens in the decorations added by the window manager. Simply put, you can't process events that happen in the window border or title area.